# What are the VERY basic dependencies for a JSF project?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

I am trying to learn JSF.

Can someone give me the LEAST required dependencies for a JSF project which will be built to a war file which says Hello world? I guess I need a servlet, and apache myfaces?

It would be better if it is in terms of maven dependencies.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest setup is to download TomEE (it includes Servlet and JSF). Then use the following as Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

An example of one of the most basic JSF apps possible: [Minimal 3-tier Java EE app, without any XML config](http://jdevelopment.nl/minimal-3tier-java-ee-app-xml-config)